# antlr4: perplexed about whitespace handling

Tags: whitespace, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I know this question has been asked in more or less the same terms before, but none of the answers are working for me:

```
grammar Problem;
top: (IDENT | INT)*;
IDENT: (ALPHA|'_') (ALPHA|DIGIT|'_')*;
INT: DEC_INT | HEX_INT;
DEC_INT: (ZERO | (NZERO_DIGIT DIGIT*));
HEX_INT: ZERO X HEX+;
ZERO: '0';
NZERO_DIGIT: '1'..'9';
DIGIT: '0'..'9';
ALPHA: [a-zA-Z];
HEX: [0-9a-fA-F];
X: [xX];
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

When I give this input to the parser:

```
0xFF ZZ123
```

followed by a newline and ctrl-D, it gets parsed as :

```
(top 0xFF ZZ123)
```

Which is the intended behaviour.

However when I give this input to the parser:

```
0xFFZZ123
```

followed by a newline and ctrl-D, it gets parsed as :

```
(top 0xFF ZZ123)
```

which is not at all intended. I would like this to trigger a lexer error, considering this as a misspelled HEX_INT.

If I disable whitespace skipping, I still get the same lexer behaviour (a single group of chars parsed as two tokens), however since WS tokens are now reported to the parser, I get the following error:

```
0XFFZZ123
line 1:9 extraneous input '\n' expecting {<EOF>, IDENT, INT}
(top 0XFF ZZ123 \n)
```

And in addition I cannot type space separated tokens anymore (normal since top does not mention WS):

```
0XFF ZZ123
line 1:4 extraneous input ' ' expecting {<EOF>, IDENT, INT}
(top 0XFF   ZZ123)
```

I have tried to fix the grammar by disabling whitespace skipping and changing the top rule to :

```
top: WS* (IDENT | INT) (WS+ (IDENT|INT))* WS*;
```

However if I enter the following stream to the parser,

```
0xFF ZZ123 0XFFZZ123
```

I get this error:

```
line 1:20 extraneous input 'ZZ123' expecting {<EOF>, WS}                                        
(top     0xFF   ZZ123     0xFF ZZ123 \n)
```

Where you can still see that the last input token  has been split in OxFF and ZZ123, whereas I would really trigger a lexing error here instead of having to handle whitespace in the parser explicitly.

So what combination of tricks do I have to use to obtain the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a token that accepts erroneous tokens like 0XFFZZ123, and place it just before WS. For example:

```
grammar SandBox;
top: (IDENT | INT)*;
IDENT: (ALPHA|'_') (ALPHA|DIGIT|'_')*;
INT: DEC_INT | HEX_INT;
DEC_INT: (ZERO | (NZERO_DIGIT DIGIT*));
HEX_INT: ZERO X HEX+;
ZERO: '0';
NZERO_DIGIT: '1'..'9';
DIGIT: '0'..'9';
ALPHA: [a-zA-Z];
HEX: [0-9a-fA-F];
X: [xX];

ERROR_TOKEN: (~[ \t\r\n])+;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

What happens is the following. If you input 0xFF ZZ123, then INT and IDENT win, because of their position. If you input 0XFFZZ123, then ERROR_TOKEN wins, because of the length (length has priority over position). Since ERROR_TOKEN is not part of the "top", an error would be raised.

I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: You can even improve this version by adding more specific error token rules just before ERROR_TOKEN. This way you can give more specific error messages. One would be a "MISSPELLED_HEX_NUMBER" token.

Comment: Another way would be to allow the lex/parse and handle it afterwards. Don't put too much into the lexer/parser. As long as valid input is parsed correctly and invalid input can be easily recognized afterwards, it's better - in many cases - to let the invalid input be parsed.

Comment: Adding an extra error token is hard to handle in the parser that uses this lexer, since the error token can popup in any place.
It seems strange, but as soon as the lexer is used in the context of a parser, the problem dissapears, and the example triggers a parsing error. It might be due to the fact that no grammar rule recogizes an int followed by another int or identifier without any operator in between.